# Creating file using GitHub API with Delphi

Tags: rest, delphi

I am trying to use the GitHub API with the Delphi REST components to create a file in a repo. I have successfully done this from Python and a curl call, but after much effort, I can't seem to get it to work from Delphi using the provided REST components. I have successfully done GETs using the Delphi components. The curl command that works is:

```
curl -X PUT \
  -H "Authorization: token ghp_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"   
   https://api.github.com/repos/<user>/TestRepo/contents/test.txt \
   -d '{"message": "Add File", "content": "bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM="}'
```

I've swapped out the user name and hidden the token but this call works.

The equivalent Delphi code I used was:

```
procedure TfrmMain.addFile;
begin
  RESTClient1.BaseURL := 'https://api.github.com';
  RESTRequest1.Client := RESTClient1;
  RESTRequest1.Resource := '/repos/<user>/TestRepo/contents/test.txt';
  RESTRequest1.Method := rmPUT;
  RESTRequest1.AddParameter('Authorization', 'ghp_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', pkHTTPHEADER);
  RESTRequest1.AddParameter('message', 'Add File', pkREQUESTBODY);
  RESTRequest1.AddParameter('content', 'bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM=', pkREQUESTBODY);
  RESTRequest1.Execute;
  Memo1.text := RESTResponse1.JSONValue.ToString;
end;
```

The response I get is:

```
{"message":"Not 
Found","documentation_url":"https:\/\/docs.github.com\/rest\/reference\/repos#create-or- 
update-file-contents"}
```

I've also tried using the Delphi REST Debugger, and I get the same error message.

I tried changing

```
  RESTRequest1.AddParameter('Authorization', 'ghp_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', pkHTTPHEADER);
```

to

```
  RESTRequest1.AddParameter('Authorization', 'token ghp_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', pkHTTPHEADER);
```

just in case that was the issue but no difference. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of AddParameter for the body is wrong. The resulting content will not automatically be JSON. Try it this way:

```
  RESTClient1.BaseURL := 'https://api.github.com';
  RESTRequest1.Client := RESTClient1;
  RESTRequest1.Resource := 'repos/<user>/TestRepo/contents/test.txt';
  RESTRequest1.Method := rmPUT;
  RESTRequest1.AddAuthParameter('Authorization', 'token ghp_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);
  RESTRequest1.AddBody(TJSONObject.Create.AddPair('message', 'Add File').AddPair('content', 'bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM='), ooREST);
  RESTRequest1.Execute;
```

Comment: I was hopeful that your solution might but unfortunately I get the same error message.  Is there a way to see what the rest call is actually sending to the server?

Comment: You can inspect GetFullRequestURL and GetFullRequestBody. I assume that the placeholder <user> and the token value in your code are replaced with real values?

Comment: Yes I replaced those values.

Comment: This is what is coming from the two calls (replaced my user name with <user>:

https://api.github.com/repos/<user>/TestRepo/contents/test.txt

{"message":"Add File","content":"bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM="} which look ok

Comment: I modified your AddBody call to add the content field (I assumed it was a typo in your code) so what I actually used was:

  RESTRequest1.AddBody(TJSONObject.Create.AddPair('message', 'Add File').AddPair('content', 'bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM='), ooREST);

Comment: I updated my answer. There is an additional parameter to the `AddAuthParameter` call.

Comment: It worked. Many thanks. I would never have figured this out myself.